# Slider PointerPressed not firing

Tags: xaml, slider, microsoft-metro, windows-8.1

I have slider on my page, and i try to handle PonterPressed Event using Behaviors SDK.
But the event not firing. I found this:

[PointerPressed not working on left click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14767020/pointerpressed-not-working-on-left-click)

and it works. But I don't uderstand why I can't do that with XAML. I'd rather not use code behind.

Answer (score 0):

the slider-control might block the event from getting raised.

You could consider extending the slider control and registering your event handler on the appropriate template-part of the control (Thumb or Rail maybe) to raise a custom event you can handle outside (or change a dependency property you can bind to)

greetings