# UWP - pointer pressed not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, blend, event-triggers

I am working on a Universal windows app. I added an EventTrigger to my listboxitems.

```
<Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
  <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
    <Core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding GoToHotelsCommand}"/>
  </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
</Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

When i use EventName="Tapped", it does what it is suppose to do. But when i use EventName="PointerPressed", nothing is triggered. The 'Tapped' trigger does solve my problem, but i was curious why it won't work with pointer pressed. isn't the Pointer pressed eventtrigger's purpose to be triggered when the pointer is pressed? Or am i missing something?

Comment: Is pointerpressed not working when using a pointer device, like a mouse?

Comment: yes, it is not working with a mouse

Comment: Hadn't ran into the issue yet but it appears you're not the only one with the issue judging by a quick google search. Wish I had an answer for ya, but there are some pretty sharp MSFT'ers that frequent here I could think of that might educate both of us.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually `Tapped` fires on/after `PointerReleased` event...

Answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14767020/pointerpressed-not-working-on-left-click):

```
SomeButton.AddHandler(PointerPressedEvent, new PointerEventHandler(SomeButton_PointerPressed), true);
```