# ComboBoxItem PointerEntered Event is not fired in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp

```
<Grid>
<ComboBox x:Name="ColorRepresentationComboBox" Margin="0,12,0,0"  Width="120" >
<ComboBoxItem x:Name="HEXComboBoxItem" Content="HEX" PointerPressed="HEXComboBoxItem_PointerPressed"/>
<ComboBoxItem x:Name="HSLComboBoxItem" Content="HSL" PointerPressed="HSLComboBoxItem_PointerPressed"/>
</ComboBox>
   </Grid>



private void HEXComboBoxItem_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{

}

private void HSLComboBoxItem_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

PointerEntered Event work properly,but pointerPressed event is not fired.I dont Know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, it should be that the `PointerPressed` event has been specially handled inside the `ComboBox`.

If you want to capture the click event of `ComboBoxItem`, you can consider using `Tapped` event.

```xml
<ComboBoxItem x:Name="HEXComboBoxItem" Content="HEX" Tapped="HEXComboBoxItem_Tapped"/>
```

```cs
private void HEXComboBoxItem_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("tapped");
}
```

---

If you just want to get the selected item after the `ComboBox` selected item is changed, you can consider using this method:

```xml
<ComboBox SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged">
    <ComboBoxItem x:Name="HEXComboBoxItem" Content="HEX" Tapped="HEXComboBoxItem_Tapped"/>
</ComboBox>
```

```cs
private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var item = (sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem;
    // do other things...
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's an easy solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14767020/pointerpressed-not-working-on-left-click). It says:

These events have to be handled not through XAML but thorugh AddHandler method.

```cs
SomeButton.AddHandler(PointerPressedEvent, 
    new PointerEventHandler(SomeButton_PointerPressed), true);
```